# NSFetchedResults Returning Old Data After Saving the Persistent MOC

Tags: ios, core-data

### Context

I've a simple Core Data stack: `MainQueueMOC -> PrivateBackgroundMOC -> PersistentStoreCoordinator` that is managed by my `TTPersistenceManager` that looks like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, TTPersistenceType) {
    TTPersistenceTypeInMemory,
    TTPersistenceTypeSQLite
};

@interface TTPersistenceManager : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext; // this is the MainQueueMOC

- (id)initWithPersistenceType:(TTPersistenceType)persistenceType;
- (void)initializeCoreData;

- (void)save;
- (void)persist;
```

**Currently we only use the in memory store.**

It is inspired by this [article from Marcus Zarra](http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/). So the MainQueueMOC is the single source of truth, and the PrivateBackgroundMOC is only used to save to the store in background, and it is never publicly exposed. If you read the article you'll notice that I added a method called `persist`, the difference between `save` and `persist` is:

- `save`, saves the MainQueueMOC using `performBlockAndWait`
- `persist`, saves the MainQueueMOC using `performBlockAndWait` and the PrivateBackgroundMOC using `performBlock`

I did mostly because of these two paragraphs:

> As a rule, any time we are leaving the application we want to call save on the persistence controller. This guarantees that if we get killed while paused, we will not be losing data.
>
> In most cases this is the only place you need to call save on the main and private contexts.

So `save` is the method that saves the single source of truth and we call it after any change to a managed object, while `persist` is only called on the app delegate when the goes to background or is about to be terminated to save all the changes to the store.

This works fine except for the following problem.

### The Problem

We have a `NSFetchedResultsController` with a predicate like this:

```
item.kind = "relationship" AND item.relationship.archived == NO
```

We don't show items that are associated with an archived relationship. The user can swipe on the row to Archive it, which that changes `relationship.archived = @YES`, calls `[TTPersistenceManager save]`, and refetch the `NSFetchedResultsController` and that item disappear from the list. This works.

Until we enter background for the first time.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self.persistenceController persist];
}
```

After calling `persist`, if a user swipes to Archive the item does not disappear from the list.

```
relationship.archived = @YES; // item at index 0 is associated with this object
[self.persistenceManager save];
[self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]; // Works, no error

item = [[self.fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] firstObject];
NSLog(@"item is archived %d", item.relationship.archived);
// prints: item is archived 1
```

The `relationship` object has its `archived` property set to `YES` but the fetch still returns it.

### The Possible Solutions

I've found two possible solutions. But I want to choose the more correct one, the one that will work as expected in all cases regardless if we using in-memory store or sqlite.

\1. Add a `updatedAt` attribute to `item` that we set the current date every time we update `relationship`:

```
 relationship.item.updatedAt = [NSDate date];
 relationship.archived = @YES;
 [self.persistenceManager save];
```

\2. Always call `persist` instead of `save`:

```
relationship.archived = @YES;
[self.persistenceManager persist];
```

What is the correct approach?

Is my assumption that we only to save the MOC connected to the persistent store when going into background?

Why does adding an attribute to `item` that is not even used in the predicate works?

---

**Update: Source Code**

```
@implementation TTPersistenceManager

- (id)initWithPersistenceType:(TTPersistenceType)persistenceType {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _persistenceType = persistenceType;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initializeCoreData {
    FCYAssert(!self.managedObjectModel, @"CoreData has already been initialized");

    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    self.managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:@[bundle]];
    self.persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:self.managedObjectModel];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSPersistentStore *store = [self.persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:[self storageType] configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:&error];
    FCYAssert(store != nil, @"Failed create persistent store: %@\n%@", [error localizedDescription], [error userInfo]);

    self.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator;
    self.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;

    self.managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
    self.managedObjectContext.parentContext = self.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext;
    self.managedObjectContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyStoreTrumpMergePolicy;
}

- (void)persist {
    if (![self saveContext:self.managedObjectContext]) return;
    [self saveContext:self.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
}

- (void)save {
    [self saveContext:self.managedObjectContext];
}

#pragma mark - Private

- (NSString *)storageType {
    if (self.persistenceType == TTPersistenceTypeSQLite) return NSSQLiteStoreType;
    return NSInMemoryStoreType;
}

- (BOOL)saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    NSError *error = nil;
    BOOL didSave = [self saveContext:context error:&error];

    if (!didSave) {
        TTLogError(@"Error saving context: %@\n\nUser Info:\n%@\n\nCall Stack:\n%@", error.localizedDescription, error.userInfo, [NSThread callStackSymbols]);
    }

    return didSave;
}

- (BOOL)saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context error:(NSError **)errorPtr {
    __block BOOL hasChanges = NO;

    [context performBlockAndWait:^{
        hasChanges = [context hasChanges];
    }];

    if (!hasChanges) return YES;

    __block NSError *error = nil;
    __block BOOL didSave = NO;

    [context performBlockAndWait:^{
        didSave = [context save:&error];
    }];

    if (!didSave && error && errorPtr) {
        *errorPtr = error;
    }

    return didSave;
}

@end
```

**NSFetchedResultsController**

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)setupFetchedResultsController {
    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:[TTInboxItem entityName]];
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:TTInboxItemAttributes.sortDate ascending:NO]];

        NSPredicate *itemPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", TTInboxItemAttributes.type, [TTRelationship entityName]];
        NSPredicate *notArchivedPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K.%K != %@", TTInboxItemRelationships.relationship, TTRelationshipAttributes.archived, @YES];
        NSPredicate *notArchivedPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[itemPredicate, notArchivedPredicate]];

        fetchRequest.predicate = notArchivedPredicate;

        self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                            managedObjectContext:self.persistenceManager.managedObjectContext
                                                                              sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                       cacheName:nil];

        self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self.tableViewBatchUpdater;
        [self fetchInboxItems];
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your stack creation and fetch results controller creation code?

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra done, added source for `TTPersistenceManager` and the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

Comment: When this situation happens, are you seeing your delegate methods of your `NSFetchedResultsController` fire?  What version of iOS are you running this against?

Comment: FYI, put the notArchived first in your compound predicate.  You will get better performance.

Comment: Are you calling `-performFetch:` after every swipe to Archive?  `-performFetch:` should only be called once in the lifecycle of the `NSFetchedResultsController` and from there the delegate methods handle any changes to the data even if those changes are coming from the table view.

Comment: And another thought while we are here.  Try disabling your merge policies.  Just comment out those lines of code.  As I think through the permutations of this, I wonder if you are getting trumped by a save to the store firing asynchronously when you go into background...

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra Using iOS 7 and 8, the delegate methods don't fire when archiving. Yes, I'm calling `performFetch:` after every swipe to Archive otherwise I get `Invalid update: invalid number of rows...`. Removing the merge policy **seems to** make it more reliable but doesn't fix it.

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` delegate doesn't detect changes in the relationships, that is why I get the "invalid update" if I don't call `performFetch:` every time.

Comment: If you are getting an Invalid update, you have something else going wrong in your delegate methods.  Having the archive flag on the other side of a relationship like that is ... questionable.  Assuming there is a reason for that you will want to "tickle" the primary object to get the delegate methods to fire instead of constantly calling `-performFetch:` which is super expensive and causes some massive table refreshes.

Comment: The delegate only gets fired if I "tickle" the primary object, it works fine once it gets "tickled". Thank you very much for all the info it helped a lot. Things I did: made my save just like yours, and persist is just like save but it blocks until everything is finished useful in the app delegate. Next thing I'll do is refactor this area to avoid the relationship and make the code simpler with no need to re-fetch.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a similar problem with one of my apps. This hint in the documentation helped me in figuring out a solution.

From Apple:

> If a context’s parent store is a persistent store coordinator, then changes are committed to the external store. If a context’s parent store is another managed object context, then save: only updates managed objects in that parent store. To commit changes to the external store, you must save changes in the chain of contexts up to and including the context whose parent is the persistent store coordinator.

Since you have this structure `MainQueueMOC -> PrivateBackgroundMOC -> PersistentStoreCoordinator` you should try to get a hold of your contexts and do something like `[TTPersistenceManager.managedObjectContext save]`. Maybe make a method for calling save and your contexts if you have more than one.

As to "Is my assumption that we only to save the MOC connected to the persistent store when going into background?" You can save as much as you want but always check is you have changes you can do something like this on your `applicationDidEnterBackground:` so you don't waste time. I do save changes manually on my apps since I know exactly when a change is needed. I rely on the code above for the background saves.

From Apple:

> Always verify that the context has uncommitted changes (using the hasChanges property) before invoking the save: method. Otherwise, Core Data may perform unnecessary work.

```
if (TTPersistenceManager.managedObjectContext.hasChanges) {
    [TTPersistenceManager.managedObjectContext save]
}
```

Why does adding an attribute to item that is not even used in the predicate works?

I think this has more to do with the fetch request than the persistent store. I believe this is related to your earlier statement. "The relationship object has its archived property set to YES but the fetch still returns it." I think once you solve your persist issue your fetchRequest should not return the item.

Comment: BTW I've updated the post with source code in case you want to take a second look.

Comment: More details. `TTPersistenceManager` is injected into any class that needs access to core data read or write, so I always call `save` after making changes to a managed object. About your last paragraph, if I always call `persist` I don't need the extra attribute, the solutions are exclusive not together.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read the article and I haven't read through all your code but MOCs cache data and even a fetch doesn't force it to go the database again. So listen to the NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification notification and merge changes manually? **.. mainly because you need to tell the fetch results controller (!) as it also has a cache**

Comment: The `NSFetchedResultsController` already listens for `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`.  That is the primary reason to use it.  Also, in his code he has the `NSFetchedResultsController` cache disabled.